# How to use Minicom programmatically without console input?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, serial-port, file-transfer, minicom

is there a way to use the Minicom functions in a python script? I need to transfer files via serial port on a raspberry pi 4 to another raspberry pi 4. Minicom offers this functionality and it works indeed when using the console interface.

But I need to trigger the file transfer automatically in my python script and I am not able to type this in the console.

Any kind of feedback is always appreciated.

Thanks.
Michael

Comment: I would imagine you could do it fairly easily with `pexpect`. See https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Hallo @MarkSetchell. Looks like that this is what I need.
I am already struggeling when spawing my minicom process, as there is no actual process generated.
I am using: 
child = pexpect.spawn("minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyS0")

When I am  checking my current processes with 
ps -ef | grep minicom

There is no such process....
Can you help?

Comment: Hello @MarkSetchell. I get my process now, but I can not parse the response with:
child.expect("CTRL-Z", timeout=120)

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can look at my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76703024/how-to-use-pexpect-with-minicom